# R S3 how to get

Tags: r

My question is: What is best way to get an object attributes from argument passed into function.
For example, below I show sample from my code.

```
  tsdScene <- function(...){
  scene <- list(..., sceneLength = length(list(...)), tsdList = list(...))
  class(scene) <- "tsdScene" 
  return(scene)
  }
```

So as a tsdList I get all objects passed into a function (in this example it's object s1 and object s2 from another class). Now when I use:

```
test <- tsdScene(s1,s2)
test$tsdList
```

I get as a return:

```
$freq
[1] 12
```

But when I try to use

```
test$tsdList$freq
```

I get NULL. And this is my main question. How can I get this $freq argument?I will be thankful for any tip.

Comment: Welcome at SO! Please add the missing example data to your question (variables `s1` and `s2`) to give as a minimal reproducible example that we can use to help you. THX :-)

Comment: We'll need to see your data to find out what the issue is, because your idea should work.  For example:  `one <- list(two = list(three = 1:10)); one$two$three`

Comment: If you call `tsdScene` with two arguments you will get a list `test$tsdList` with two members, there is something missing in your question, the values of both `s1` and `s2` and the full output of `test$tsdList`. Since you are passing two arguments maybe you want `test$tsdList[[1]]$freq` or `test$tsdList[[2]]$freq`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call `tsdScene` with two arguments you will get a list `test$tsdList` with two members.

Maybe you want `test$tsdList[[1]]$freq` or `test$tsdList[[2]]$freq`.

```
s1 <- 1
s2 <- list(freq = 12)
test <- tsdScene(s1, s2)
test$tsdList
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]]$freq
#[1] 12


test$tsdList[[2]]
#$freq
#[1] 12
```

So you can access `freq` with

```
test$tsdList[[2]]$freq
#[1] 12
```

Comment: Thank you for help with this task. Truly this is the answer :). Thanks once agian.